# Wordpress Update Post Hook in Admin View

Tags: php, wordpress

i need a hook for the moment when an admin updates a post. (Click on update button). After the post is successfully updated.

The reason is, i have to call a function to update something for another plugin.

Everything i tried so far, is not working.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse41912_save_post' );
add_action( 'edit_post', 'wpse41912_edit_post' );
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse41912_transition_post_status' );
add_filter( "edit_post_{$field}", 'filter_edit_post_field', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'admin_head_post_editing' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php',  'admin_head_post_new' );
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'admin_head_post_listing' );
```

In Everything function i wrote this, and i didnt see the echo or the alert box.

```
echo "my_update_user_meta";
$text = "my_update_user_meta";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $text . '")</script>';
```

Edit: i was missing the 3,4th parameter.
My Code now

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mmx_save_post_action', 10, 3 );
function mmx_save_post_action( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { // keine Aktion bei Autosave
    //autosave
  }else{
    //no autosave
    if ( is_admin() && current_user_can( 'manage_options' )  ) {
      //admin panel && permission ok
     //call function
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a post is updated there are some hooks that are fired:

- **`'pre_post_update'`** is an action fired just **before** the post is updated, the argument passed are 2: `$post_ID` and `$data` that is an array of **all** the other database colums of the post table
- **`'transition_post_status'`** is an hook fired on update, and pass 3 arguments: $new_post_status, `$old_post_status` and `$post` (object).
- Then, there are other 2 transition hooks fired, but they are dynamic named, it means that the effective action fired depends on the old and the new post status.
  **`"{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}"`** and **`"{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}"`**. First pass the only the post object as argument, the second pass the post id and the post object. Find documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).
- **`'edit_post'`** that pass 2 arguments: `$post_ID` and `$post` (object)
- **`'post_updated'`** that pass 3 arguments: `$post_ID`, `$post_after` (post object after the  update), `$post_before` (post object before the update)
- Another dynamic hook: **`"save_post_{$post->post_type}"`** that depends on post type, e.g. for standard posts is `'save_post_post'` and for pages is `'save_post_page'`, this hook pass 3 arguments: `$post_ID`, `$post` (object) and `$update` that is a boolean (true or false) that is true when you perform an update, in fact this hook is fired also when a post is saved for first time.
- **'`save_post`'** that is fired both on update and on first saving, and pass the same 3 arguments of the previous hook.
- **'`save_post_{$post_type}`'** that is fired both on update and on first saving, and pass the same first 2 arguments of the previous hook.
- Finally you have **'`wp_insert_post`'**, that is fired both on update and on first saving, and pass the same 3 arguments of the previous 2 hooks.

These hook are fired every time a post is updated, both via admin pages in backend and via when updated "manually" using [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) or [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) functions.

When the post is updated using admin pages there are additional hooks fired, an example is **`'update_post_redirect'`** or **`'post_updated_messages'`**. (See [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59118/35541) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/29254/35541)  WPSE answers for usage examples).

Note that if you want make use of some hooks argument, that isn't the first, one you have to explicitly declare it in `add_action` call.

E.g. if you want to use the `'$update'` argument (that is the 3rd) of the `'save_post'` hook you need to add `3` as `$accepted_args` param on `add_action` ([see docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)):

```
// if you don't add 3 as as 4th argument, this will not work as expected
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_function', 10, 3 );

function my_save_post_function( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
  $msg = 'Is this un update? ';
  $msg .= $update ? 'Yes.' : 'No.';
  wp_die( $msg );
}
```

Last note regard *timing*: you must be sure that `add_action` is called *before* the action is triggered, or it will do nothing.

E.g. this code:

```
wp_update_post( $post );
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function', 10, 3 );
```

will do nothing, because the action is added after the hook is fired. Here is simple to recognize it, in real world code isn't always so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I was missing the 3,4 argument (,10,3).  Maybe you can help me with this now. I just want that the function i will call is just fired,if im in admin view, the admin (or another role) is logged in, no autosave.

Comment: i already have this to check the permission if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
      echo "current_user_can manage options1";
  } else {
      echo "current_user_cant  manage options1";
  }